# Android picks wrong resource folder

Tags: android, layout, resources

I seem to have some problems with my resource folder - Android chooses the wrong resource folder.

When in design mode, in the layout editor, I have the option to choose between different devices, to look at my design in different screen resolutions. I have specified three different devices, one for each resolution.
The mdpi and hdpi shows the resources from the right folder, but when choosing my device with ldpi, it shows the resources from mdpi - which is wrong.

**The settings for ldpi device is:**

Small, Not Long, Portrait, Low Density, Finger, Soft, No Keys, Trackball, 320x240

When I run the program I get an InflateException , because it cannot find the right resources for my imageview in my layout: android:src="@drawable/psbgtop"

**This is my res folder:**

- res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
- res/drawable-hdpi/psbgbottom.png
- res/drawable-hdpi/psbgtop.png
- res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
- res/drawable-ldpi/psbgbottom.png
- res/drawable-ldpi/psbgtop.png
- res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
- res/drawable-mdpi/psbgbottom.png
- res/drawable-mdpi/psbgtop.png
- res/layout/main.xml
- res/layout/settings.xml
- res/layout/settings2.xml
- res/layout/synchronize.xml
- res/values/strings.xml
- res/xml/preferences.xml

Can anyone figure out, why my folder structure seems to be wrong?

Best regards
Frederik

Comment: It would also be useful to supply the logcat output, containing the java exception and any logs prior to that related to resource lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "aapt dump restable" to look at the actual resources in your .apk.  There is no need to have a base resource when using density resources.  There isn't enough information here to help much more than that, but my guess would be just that your code and resources are out of sync.  Have you tried doing a full clean build?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that my question lacks some information. I'm building against Android 2.0 SDK and my manifest file describes minSDK as "<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />".

Comment: I've dumped the resources here: http://pastebin.com/TzXWxaYr . I will be very grateful to hear from you. I think I can guess what the lines mean, but I can't find any documentation on this command.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to have a "base" folder (called "drawable" in your particular case) and put some "default" resources there so that Android has something to revert to, if it doesn't locate right resources. But in general it indeed looks strange, why none of dpi-specific resources were not picked.

Comment: Yeah, well I know that would work, but then again that's not what I want. Almost every tutorial states only that the three dpi folders are necessessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you get the runtime error is because you're testing/compiling it against Android SDK 1.5.

If you aim for 1.5 compatibility, you also need a default "drawable" folder, as of the official documentation, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and nodpi modes were added with API Level 4 (Android 1.6).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

```
ldpi: Low-density screens; approximately 120dpi.
mdpi: Medium-density (on traditional HVGA) screens; approximately 160dpi.
hdpi: High-density screens; approximately 240dpi.
nodpi: This can be used for bitmap resources that you do not want to be scaled to match the device density.

Added in API Level 4.
```

Edit: 
If I'd be you, I'd simply rename the `drawable-ldpi` folder into `drawable` folder and store the ldpi files in `drawable`